# Where is X11's error log located in OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, x11

I'm trying to run the Xmonad window manager in X11 on OSX lion, I load Xmonad at x11 startup, and X11 just crashes, sometimes it does not. I'm just wondering how I can view some kind of error log to ascertain why it is crashing.

**Solution:**

The log file I needed was `system.log` in `/private/var/log/system.log`

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you looked in `/Library/Logs/CrashReporter`? Or `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter`?

Comment: The log file is within /var. Have you followed the steps in http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Frequently_asked_questions specifically section 4.1.3?

Answer (score 2):

1. Fire up Terminal
2. `cat /private/var/log/system.log`

This will get up the System Log and let you see what is going on. You should be able to find the results you need in there.

If need be, pass that onto the `grep` command get it to find the strings you want.

`cat /private/var/log/system.log | grep [string]`

This will output the strings you requrie to the screen specifically.